# Javascript code for smooth scroll on website doesn't work after update on Contao version

Tags: javascript, smoothing

I made a smooth scroll using JavaScript in my layout, but after refreshing, the script doesn't work.

Every time I have a same error:

Script:

```js
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#mmenu], [href=#article-38])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href=#article-38]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

And these are the errors:

```js
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#mmenu], [href=#article-38])
    at Function.oe.error (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.html:62)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    
    
    jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#article-38]
    at Function.oe.error (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home.html:78)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

This is the script that I used in my Contao web site, and after site update, the script doesn't work.

I tried many changes, but none of them worked.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some of the markup by any chance? P.S. Including a hash like that isn't going to work. Try these two: 1) ```$('a:not([href*=mmenu], [href*=article-38])')``` 2) ```$('a[href*=article-38]')```?

Comment: Put `"` around `#` like this, $('a[href*="#"]:not([href=#mmenu], [href=#article-38])')

Comment: And `"` around `#article-38` for `$('a[href="#article-38"]')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This changes are solved errors, but smooth still not work...

Comment: try downgrading the said `contao` maybe it is not compatible, or some kind.

Comment: I am sure is not compatible with last Contao version, but my customer want fresh version, and this is why I updated site.

Answer (score 0):

This is my smooth menu. It work, but without smooth effect...

```html
<div id="smoothscroll-menu">
 <div id="nav-header" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Start</p><a href="#article-38"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont1" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page1</p><a href="#cont1"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont2" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page2</p><a href="#cont2"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont3" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page3</p><a href="#cont3"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont4" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page4</p><a href="#cont4"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont5" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page5</p><a href="#cont5"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-cont6" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Page6</p><a href="#cont6"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-partner" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Partner</p><a href="#partner"></a></div>
 <div id="nav-footer" class="scmenu-dot"><p class="tooltip">Kontakt</p><a href="#footer"></a></div>
</div>
```